# Count number of items in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my code. 
I am trying to get number of trade offers through steam API.
I can get an array but i dont know how to count number of items from this array

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v0001/?key=KEY&get_received_offers=1&active_only=1";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

How can I get the number of [trade_offers_recived] ? Currently there are 2 trade offers recived (0 and 1)

Comment: See http://www.php.net/count

Comment: I tryed $dataCount  = count($data);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($dataCount, true) . '</pre>'; . But it is not counting what i want .

Comment: You should count the field you want to count instead.

Comment: $dataCount = count($data['response']['trade_offers_received']); // is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $data array contains "response" arrays, and these "trade_offers_received" arrays. So try this:

```
$numtradeoffers = count($data['response']['trade_offers_received']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `count` can be used even for sub-array of your array.

So if you need count of elements in a sub-array, which is under key `'trade_offers_recived'` which is in turn under key `response`:

```
echo count($data['response']['trade_offers_received']);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have linked above your array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [trade_offers_received] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    ...
```

So you just need to do the count on the trade_offers_received key:

```
<?php
print count($data['response']['trade_offers_received']);
```